# Minecraft Server not letting me build in survival but will in creative

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I am building my Minecraft Server as we speak but what I have noticed is that when I'm in the survival game mode it will not let me place, brake or touch anything on the server... it won't even let me use the adminshop sign to sell or buy an item. When im in creative everything works but my server is a survival server not a creative server so when players join they will not be able to do anything on my server. How do I fix this?
If anyone knows what is going on please help!!!
I also should let you know that I am using a hosting website for my server through APEX Minecraft hosting. 
If someone can help me fix this I will put the IP address out on this page!!! 
thanks you to anyone with any information

Comment: It looks like you run a Spigot server or similar and you have some sort of protection plugin preventing you from doing anything.

Comment: What plugin could be doing this?

Comment: That's what you should tell us. We don't know what you've installed. My guess is that your permissions are not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, where it has the player list, make sure you are not a visitor(with the yellow hand icon next to your name). This is probably just some operator status person pranking you.